# How to convert a MVP matrix of a NDC of 2x2x2 to a MVP matrix of a NDC of 2x2x1 cube (Metal)?

Tags: xcode, matrix, projection, metal, metalkit

How to convert a MVP matrix of a NDC of 2x2x2 cube with center at 0 (openGL) to a MVP matrix of a NDC of 2x2x1 cube with its center at (0, 0, 0.5) (Metal) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://metashapes.com/blog/opengl-metal-projection-matrix-problem/) has good explanation of converting a matrix from OpenGL to Metal.

> For Metal with its specific NDC, we could either derive the matrix in
>   a similar fashion or use the easy way: transform OpenGL’s NDC to
>   Metal’s NDC. This is done by doing a post multiplication which first
>   scales the 2x2x2 cube to 2x2x1 and then shifts it by 0.5 to have the
>   correct center:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @0xBFE1A8 ! I will try to see how to do it, not sure I understand the equation :(